# Hyperbolic groups and spaces of negative curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geometric-group-theory, open-problems, negative-curvature

Mikhail Gromov states that he "tried for about 10 years to prove that every hyperbolic group is realizable by a space of negative curvature" in his interview with Martin Raussen and Christian Skau (page 6, link below). Is there any information available about the current status of this conjecture?

https://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/rtx100300391p.pdf

Comment: It is an open problem if every hyperbolic group acts isometrically properly dis continuously and cocompactly on a CAT(-1) space. But every hyperbolic group is quasi-isometric to such space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, it is still unknown whether hyperbolic groups are CAT(-1) or even CAT(0). A related question is:

> Let $G$ be a hyperbolic group (endowed with a finite generated set). If $d$ is sufficiently large, does there exist a $G$-equivariant CAT(-1) or CAT(0) metric defined on the Rips complex $P_d(G)$?

This question is also open, but a counterexample is given [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1939) (Corollary 5.10) for $P_d(X)$ where $X$ is a specific (locally infinite) quasi-tree.

An alternative approach is to replace Rips' complex with the injective hull of the group.  See the last paragraph of the introduction of Lang's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.5971).

Actually, even the following question is open:

> Let $G$ be a hyperbolic group acting geometrically on a CAT(0) cube complex. Does $G$ act geometrically on a CAT(-1) cube complex?

The question appears for instance [here](https://sites.google.com/a/scu.edu/rscott/pggt).

Also relevant is this [article](https://www2.math.ou.edu/~nbrady/papers/cathyp2.pdf) of Brady and Crips constructing a hyperbolic group with CAT(0) dimension two but CAT(-1) dimension three.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very interesting.